# What substitution can be used to evaluate the integral giving the area of the surface of revolution of the curve $x = \sqrt[3]{y}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, surfaces

The question is:

> Find the area of the surface generated by revolving the given curve about the $x$-axis:
>   $$x = \sqrt[3]{y}, \qquad 1 \leq y \leq 8.$$

Now, all is well, simple enough question, but to find the length by evaluating the integral of $2\pi \times (\text{radius})$ with respect to \text{length}$, we see the final form of the integrand is

$$\sqrt{{\frac{9 y ^ {4/3}+1}{9 y ^ {4/3}}}}$$

Therefore, surface area of the graph is

$$(\text{surface area}) = \int_1^8 2\pi y \sqrt{{\frac{9 y ^ {4/3}+1}{9 y ^ {4/3}}}}dy$$

What should the substitution be to solve this integral?

(A little query: How to add a space in latex instead of $\texttt{\hspace{.1cm}}$, as $\texttt{\hfill}$ doesn't work here?)

Comment: As for the MathJax query, you can use $\texttt{\text{text with spaces here}}$ to put (more or less) plain Roman (i.e., not italicized) text in equations.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Solving for $y$ shows that we can instead write the curve as
$$y = x^3, \quad 1 \leq x \leq 2,$$
so in terms of $x$ we can write the area element more tractably (in particular without nonintegral exponents) as
$$dS = 2 \pi y \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx = 2 \pi x^3 \sqrt{1 + 9x^4} dx,$$
the form of which suggests an easy substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$I = \int2\pi y \sqrt{{\frac{9 y ^ {4/3}+1}{9 y ^ {4/3}}}}dy$$ and make a first change of variable to get rid of these fractional exponents : $y ^ {4/3}=t$, $y=t^{3/4}$, $dy=\frac{3}{4 \sqrt[4]{t}}$; this makes $$I=\frac{1}{2} \pi \int \sqrt{1+9 t}\,dt$$ Now, get rid of the radical and you will end with a very simple integrand.

I am sure that ou can take from here.

Comment: Why does du/dy = d/dy(y^(4/3) not work here and why do we have to only differentiate dy/du? to find du? (i took t as u)

Comment: Please answer this ^.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I selected. Do you have problem with this ? Just post.

Comment: I upon using the substitution get stuck at this, any help? Sorry for uploading on an independent application: http://imgur.com/D6Y6AZh

Answer (score 0):

**Hin**t:Use $\tan u = 3y^{2/3} \to \tan^3 u= 27y^2 \to 3\tan^2 u \cdot sec^2 u = 54ydy$ .Can you take it from here?

Comment: no :(, simplifying I get Surface area = 2 pi Integration of sqrt (tan^3 u / 27) . 1/sin u , is that what it is supposed to come down to?